# Crystal report assembly can't be loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have installed in my windows 2008 server 64-bit and when i try to

```
* Crystal Report XI R2 service pack 6 

* Crystal Reports XI Release 2
```

open my crystal reports inside an asp.net page, i get

```
"Crystal report assembly 11.5 cannot be loaded"
```

When i go to assembly folder in the server , i can see CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine pointing to 11.5.3700.0

Any thoughts why it is not loading the crystal report?

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to my mind.

1. Check for exact version number asp.net is referring to.
2. I am not sure if this applies to Web Sites, thought it should. See if the build target is x86 or any cpu. Changing target to X86 often solves these problems. Assuming crystal reports version installed on a 64 bit system is actually 32 bit only.